# What to eat after a night workout right before sleep?

Tags: workout, nutrition, post-workout

Due my working times (software engineer), I tend to workout at times between 20 and 21 o'clock. And finish 22 o'clock.

Firs thing I do is to drink my whey isolate protein shake and then I go home. After that, I need relax a little bit and I don't have a lot of desire to eat.

Time now is 23 o'clock and I'm ready to sleep at 24 o'clock.

What should I eat: 50 grams of Quinoa with chicken breast, or an egg with a lot of cottage cheese and some bread?

What would help me without stressing my digestive system, not gaining fat and get the highest of return of investment value?

My Workout Plan:

- Lats Pulldown
- Chest Press Machine
- Deadlift
- Biceps/Triceps Superset
- Squat with Smith Machine
- Shoulder Press with Dumbbells

I also checked this question: [What to eat after a late night workout?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3388/what-to-eat-after-a-late-night-workout)

Comment: I'm doing Lat pulldown, Chest press machine, deadlift, biceps/triceps push down superset, squat with smith machine and shoulder press with dumbbells. By "The quality of those proteins is similar", do you mean that I shouldn't eat both together, only one is enough?

Comment: I've reopened the question. Please edit your workout routine into the question itself. For @DavidScarlett - Please post your comment as an answer, I think with a little expansion it would be a great answer for the question.

Answer (score 1):

Eat whatever you feel like! Keep in mind that nutrition is a cumulative process, and you don't have to worry too much about getting the precise amount of protein at a precise time as long as you eat a good amount of protein throughout the day.

For reference, this is a meta-analysis on the topic:
https://jissn.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1550-2783-10-53

"An expanded regression analysis found that any positive effects associated with protein timing on muscle protein accretion disappeared after controlling for covariates. Moreover, sub-analysis showed that discrepancies in total protein intake explained the majority of hypertrophic differences noted in timing studies. When taken together, these results would seem to refute the commonly held belief that the timing of protein intake in the immediate pre- and post-workout period is critical to muscular adaptations"

Essentially, when you eat protein and what type of protein you eat doesn't really matter as long as you eat enough protein over the course of the day. Same thing with fat; it's a matter of how many calories you eat in total, not when you eat them.

My advice is to get adequate protein, not eat too much, make healthy food choices, and don't fret too much about timing.

Comment: Aren't there things about it not being good to eat right before bed?  Maybe not directly related to working out, but still in the health section...